# nsis read from property file while installing not while creating .exe

Tags: file-io, properties, nsis

I have a situation where I want .exe to read property file from target machine.
That means we will give .exe and property file to end user.Property file will have information like tomcat port number.
So when user starts installing, installer should be able to read (e.g. tomcat port number) from property file.

This question can be considered alternative to solve problem mentioned in this link :                                        [nsis get port number on which service is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981001/nsis-get-port-number-on-which-service-is-running).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ConfigRead](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixE.html#E.2.9) is the statement that you are looking for.

```
${ConfigRead} "property_file_name" "entry_name" $result_var
```

Comment: Thanks @Seki. This cleared some of my misunderstanding regarding nsis.

Comment: You're welcome :) Feel free to search in SO archives or ask new questions if you still miss some points.